# Чтение данных из ini-файла

Tags: java, файлы, properties, ini, bufferedreader

Доброго времени суток!

Есть задача своим сервисом читать `ini` файл другого приложения, получать необходимый параметр из него, и дальше передавать его другим методам в виде `String`.

Возникла следующая проблема: если это делать через `getProperty("Path")`, то теряются наклонные черты `\` и "съедается" ближайший конец строки.

Попробовал прочитать методом `readLine()` - и сначала было так же, но потом, когда я указал кодировку `UTF-16`, строчка стала выводиться корректно.

Мне кажется немного костыльным решением читать `ini` таким образом...

Подскажите, пожалуйста как можно исправить ситуацию в случае с использованием Properties?

И корректно ли было бы обрабатывать `ini` методами вроде `readLine()`? Или все же в первую очередь - Properties?

Код тестовой реализации:

```
package com.benderje.PCC;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Properties;

public class TEST {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            readLines(createReader());
            readProps(createReader());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private static void readLines(BufferedReader reader) throws IOException {
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            if (line.startsWith("Path=")){
                System.out.println(line.substring(5));
                reader.close();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void readProps(BufferedReader reader) throws IOException {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(reader);
        System.out.println(properties.getProperty("Path"));
        reader.close();
    }

    private static BufferedReader createReader() throws FileNotFoundException {
        return new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                        new FileInputStream("TestFile.ini"), StandardCharsets.UTF_16));
    }
}
```

Вывод программы:

```
localhost:C:\DB\TestBase\
localhost:C:DBTTestBaseUser=SYSDBA
```

Фрагмент ini файла:

```
Path=localhost:C:\DB\TestBase\
User=UserLogin
Pass=$796....
DB=MAIN.GDB
Log=LOG.GDB
```

P.S. Notepad++ определяет кодировку, как UTF-16, символы конца строки везде рисует...

**UPD**
Как указал @XelaNimed в комментарии ниже, главная проблема вывода - для `Properties` *необходимо* экранировать слэши.
Т.к. мы не можем изменить этот `ini`, или как-то влиять на него, решено парсить файл в String.

**UPD2**
Поиски в интернете привели к выводу, что к проблемам с кодировками в Java могут привести такие моменты, как, например, среда, в которой запускается JVM. У нас клиенты работают как на winXP, так и на win10.
Поэтому было решено добавить проверку кодировки "костылем":

В цикле перебираем кодировки (массив кодировок из `StandartCharsets`), читаем первую строку, проверяем в ней `contains("известнаяНамСтрока")`. Если совпало - `setCharset()` и `brake`, иначе перебираем дальше...

Насколько я понял, определение кодировки файла - отдельный головняк. Если кто-то знает, как он решается грамотно, буду рад ответу...

Comment: В чём заключается необходимость использования кодировки UTF-16? Обратные слеши нужно экранировать. Приведённый Вами фрагмент INI-файла содержит корректный синтаксис Properties-файла (за исключением не экранированных обратных слешей) и почему бы Вам не использовать его, а не придумывать свой велосипед для INI-файла?

Comment: @XelaNimed а забава в том, что данный `ini` формируется не нашими силами, а программой сторонних разработчиков. 
Наша задача - подсмотреть в нем ip/localhost, который использует это приложение. 
И клиент стоит на разных машинах: и на XP, и на win10... (тут, к сожалению, вводные, которые надо принять)
И вот только под разными кодировками оно корректно читается (где UTF-8, где UTF-16).
Как я понял, это нюанс работы JVM в конкретной среде.

Comment: @XelaNimed Но да, спасибо! Почему-то не думал в сторону того, что для `properties` необходимо экранировать слэши, факт. Еще раз спасибо! 
Тогда остается только парсить этот файл, ибо, к сожалению, напрямую влиять на него мы не можем.

Answer (score -1):

```
String fileName="file:///C://temp//pro.properties";
List <String> res =  Files.readAllLines(Path.of(new URI(fileName)));
res.forEach(System.out::println);
```